# Handling multiple relational tables in data access

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, etl

I have multiple relational tables in the following format.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4J5J.png)

I'm trying to query that data in an efficient way in .Net so that I can perform transforms on the data (array to object) and insert into DocumentDb.  Essentially doing some ETL work, but because the data has to be transformed a certain way and going into DocumentDb, we are using .Net.

We are inserting into one document collection data from all relational tables, so there will be lots of 
// if still in same profile record, insert more relational data for each relational table.

We are trying to avoid cartesianing(sp?) the data so that one profile doesn't have 100 records or more.  We were thinking about using some of the Oracle methods to convert child records to a Json Array, but can't upgrade the Oracle system to the release that allows for that feature.  Another thought was to use create an xml document, but that feels pretty wrong.

Any ideas on essentially the best practice for handling ETL work within .Net?  Most of the web sites I've worked on involve only pulling from a few tables at best and a lot are 1:1 relationships.

Comment: *"We were thinking about using some of the Oracle methods to convert child records to a Json Array, but can't upgrade the Oracle system to the release that allows for that feature."* -- Are you saying Newtonsoft.Json is no longer available? Your question is too opinion based and really don't belong here. In fact, you obviously have not done much of the research on the topic

Comment: @T.S. you're assuming that they're not using Newtonsoft - which isn't necessarily valid.  The question (IMHO) is asking more about pulling back a hierarchical dataset from Oracle so that it can be transformed into something DocumentDB (?) / CosmosDB? can use.  Yes Oracle has a method for doing this but... apparently they can't use that.

Comment: Is pulling multiple results set an option?

Comment: @T.S. Definitely not saying Newtonsoft.Json is not available.  Oracle has a feature that can convert record sets into Json.  That could potentially transform one or more of the tables into one record.  I don't think my question is phrased with any opinion at all.  I'm asking what best practice is to handle pulling from lots of relational tables and being performant.  And, in fact, I have researched quite a bit and am pulling from 12+ years of experience.  Hope you have a better day than what you have experienced so far today.

Comment: Best practice is the one that suits your business best.

Answer (score 0):

You could use EntityFramework for this. Simply create a DBContext, and all the POCO classes that represent your tables with their relationships. Then execute the necessary query on your DataSet and you'll have all the data mapped to your objects, which then you can serialize in any way you want.

Comment: That's definitely a better way of pulling the data into one profile record.  I will give that a try, but I'm pulling from a tool called CIS, so I hope those play nice together.  Little worried about EF making a lot of calls or inefficient calls but just need to give it a try.  Thanks!.

Comment: @Tim EF efficiency is horrible to say the least. But it is easy to setup. Then, if you need JSON, just serialize using newtonsoft